Loss function for binned regression
Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^M$ be a feature vector and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ the corresponding target. Assume I have a multi-output model $f\colon \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}^K$. For a given constant $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^K$, I aim to predict $c_k$ such that $c_k$ is closest to $t$.
To achieve this, I define the following loss function:
$$
L(\mathbf{z}, t \mid \mathbf{c}) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\mathbf{s}^\top \mathbf{c} - t\right]^2,
$$
where $\mathbf{z} = f(\mathbf{x})$ and $s_k(\mathbf{z}) = \frac{\exp(z_k)}{\sum_{i} \exp(z_i)}$ represents the softmax function.
However, there may be non-unique solutions that minimize this loss. For instance, let $\mathbf{c} = (-1, 0, 1)^\top$ and $t = 0$. In this case:
$$
L(\mathbf{z}, t \mid \mathbf{c}) = \frac{1}{2} (s_3 - s_1)^2,
$$
and the minimum is achieved for any $s_1 \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, such that $s_1 = s_3$ and $s_2 = 1 - 2s_1$.
To address this, I add a regularization term to the loss:
$$
L(\mathbf{z}, t \mid \mathbf{c}) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\mathbf{s}^\top \mathbf{c} - t\right]^2 - \lambda H(\mathbf{s}),
$$
where $H(\mathbf{s}) = - \sum_{i} s_i \log s_i$ is the entropy of $\mathbf{s}$, and $\lambda > 0$ is a regularization parameter.
Question: Does the addition of this regularization term help to make the solution unique in most cases?
